# Which SQL clause and function allows you to filter for data about one value? (e.g. purchases made by a single customer or on a single date)

Tags: sql

Working in a data table called *Customer Data*, and that has columns tiled "customer name," "date," and "products purchased," I'm trying to isolate purchases made by a single customer throughout the year of 2018. To run a query that returns that information, What is the appropriate clause, function, and syntax that I'd need to use?

Comment: Since you are working with a date (customer purchases for a particular year) can you share what RDBMS you are working on (SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres, Redshift, etc)? The short answer though is that you use a WHERE clause like `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE customer_name = 'some customer' AND Year(date_Column) = 2018`, but again the syntax here will vary by product/RDBMS.

Comment: Or try `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_Column) = 2018`, the ANSI/ISO SQL way.

Comment: One more time, which dbms are you using?

Comment: How to use a where clause is about as basic as you can get.  There are a zillion resources out there on SQL fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get products purchased through 2018, it should just be a basic where clause. I'm not sure what dbms you are using, so I'll use MySQL with a theoretical table name of customer_data.

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer_data
WHERE YEAR(`date`) = 2018;
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) is a quick read from W3Schools on how to use the WHERE clause.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_year.asp) is a quick read from W3Schools on how to use the YEAR function.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * from [customer data]
Where [customer name] = 'John doe'
AND datepart(year, [date]) = 2018
```

OR

```
Select * from [customer data]
Where [customer name] = 'John doe'
AND ([date] Between '2018-01-01' AND '2019-01-01')
```

Comment: `datepart(year [date])` ?? which rdbms is using that syntax ?

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: That is t-sql MSSQL

Comment: your second query includes stuff from '2019-01-01'.

Comment: the [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function requires 2 argument(s).

Comment: In theory yes. 2019-01-01 defaults to 2019-01-01 00:00:000
So someone has to to the purchase exactly at that time to include 2019 results

Comment: If the column `date` has datatype DATE, and not DATETIME, the complete first januari for 2019 will be included.